# Why an instance variable can be assigned and not be referenced before its declaration in Java

Tags: java, initialization

In Java, why class A is OK but class B is with a compilation error?

```
class A {
    {a=4;}
    int a;
}

class B {
   {System.out.println(a);}//error: Cannot reference a field before it is defined
   int a;    
}
```

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/25895514/1743880

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/30959458/1743880